# User confirmation for removing previous version

Tags: c#, .net, installation

I have developed an installer from VS2010 and following are its properties:

1) product code and version are different for each deployment

2) upgrade code is same.

3) removepreviousversion = true.

Hence, the newer version gets automatically installed by removing the older version.

I want a Confirmation message like "An earlier version of this product is already installed. Do you want to remove the existing version and install the newer version . 'Yes' or 'No'"

Please provide your suggestions or ways to achieve this.

Regards,

Isha.

Comment: For the avoidance of doubt can you confirm that you wrote your own installer rather than using a ready made one?

Comment: i created an setup project from visual studio 2010

Comment: OK, thanks - then I think the answer is below.

Answer (score 3):

It is impossible using VS installer project. Use other tools for building MSI, e.g.: [WiX](http://wix.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: Thank you for your reply Kirill Polishchuk.

Comment: Is it possible to edit the upgrade table and write custom actions?

Comment: I think you need to update table with UI dialogs also. I don't think that it is the simplest way than using other tool.

Comment: You can't execute VS setup project custom actions right after executing MSI.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Do you mean that, custom actions will be executed only at the time of installation and not before install. That is the reason why we cannot write custom actions for displaying user message in this scenario . Correct me if iam wrong.

Comment: @user883822 You can display a confirmation message to the user in this case. You should provide a new dialog and write conditions so that it gets displayed when you're upgrading. I have to agree with Kirill that implementing it using WiX would be easier. Although you can edit UI tables in the MSI generated by VS installer project, you would need to do it each time you regenerate it. By the way, you can decompile an MSI package with `dark` from WiX toolset.

Comment: @Alexey Ivanov : Thanks for the reply. But i didnt understand completely.Can you provide me how to display a dialog when upgrading ? Since iam very new to this area ,can you give me some web-links / your comments on how to edit UI tables in the msi generated. It would be really helpful.